# Keep vectors of Point and vector of int in structure of one array

Tags: c++

I have to following structure of Point and int type,

```
struct PointValue{ Point p; int c; };
```

In below code, I can keep points and value manually.

```
PointValue const data[] =
    {
        { { 19, 187 }, 119 },
        { { 20, 21 }, 255 },
        { { 20, 92 }, 255 },
        { { 22, 190 }, 39 },
        { { 23, 184 }, 39 }, 
        }
```

**But...**
I want to take points and values from vectors and put in variable data.

**Edited.......**

**For example**
I have `vector <Point> pts` and `vector <int> ptsVal;`
I want to keep all points and its corresponding value to one array like in data showing above example.

But, I did this small test

```
PointValue const data[5] {};
    for (int i = 0; i < pts.size(); i++) {
        data { { {pts[i].y, pts[i].x}, ptsVal[i]} };
    }
```

**Error:**
 error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Not getting this error.
Anyone can help me to clear it.

Comment: So you have a bag of candy, and a bag of candy wraps, and you want a bag of wrapped candy. What do you do?

Comment: You need to be more specific than "it does not work".

Comment: Thanks, lemme remodify my question

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I want to take points and values from vectors and put in variable data".  Could you show some pseudo code which shows what you are trying to achieve?  Or possibly just some variables with their values before and after.

Comment: Perhaps you want [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
std::vector<Point> pts;
std::vector<int> ptsVal;

std::vector<PointValue> data;
data.reserve(pts.size());
for (int i = 0; i < (int)pts.size(); ++i)
    data.push_back({pts[i], ptsVal[i] });
```

Or, if you prefer arrays instead of vectors:

```
struct PointValue data[2];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    data[i] = {pts[i], ptsVal[i]};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but Please i am interested to work with it without vectors.

Comment: Thanks  alot. Now i am laughing on my funny coding. :)

Comment: That's the spirit :-)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have a constructor:

```
struct point{ 
    point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y){}
    int x,y; 
};
```

And try this code:

```
std::vector<PointValue> merge (const std::vector<int>& my_ints,const std::vector<point>& my_points){
   //ASSERT my_ints.size()==my_points.size()
   std::vector<PointValue> result;
   result.reserve(my_ints.size());
   for(auto it1=my_ints.begin(),it2=my_points.begin();it1!=my_ints.end();++it1,++it2){
       result.emplace_back(*it1,*it2)
   }
}
```

You may optimize the `for loop` a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the 'Point' class. If it is defined like this:

```
struct Point{
    int x,y; 
};
```

or like this:

```
struct Point{ 
    Point(int p, int q) : x(p), y(q){}
    int getX() const { return x; }
    int getY() const { return y; }

private:
    int x,y; 
};
```

That is, with a public constructor taking two integers then it should work. I ran it in gcc 4.8 and it works just fine. But, if there is no way to publicly construct `Point` from two integers then that method won't work

Comment: Yes i am using first method as you mentioned

Comment: vector<PointValue> pts(5);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    pts[i] = (PointValue){ {1,2}, 3};

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
         cout << "pts[" << i << "] = { {" << pts[i].p.x << ", " << pts[i].p.y << "} " << pts[i].c << "}\n";

Answer (score 0):

OK. Well in that case here is a working solution. *But* I am not recommending this type of coding it is just to get you working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Point{
    int x,y; 
};

struct PointValue{ Point p; int c; };

PointValue const data[] =
{
   { { 19, 187 }, 119 },
   { { 20, 21 }, 255 },
   { { 20, 92 }, 255 },
   { { 22, 190 }, 39 },
   { { 23, 184 }, 39 }
};


int main(int, char**){

    vector<PointValue> pts(5);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
       pts[i] = (PointValue){ {1,2}, 3};

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
       cout << "pts[" << i << "] = { {" << pts[i].p.x << ", " << pts[i].p.y << "} " << pts[i].c << "}\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Hope that gets you working but you might consider looking into other programming techniques some time. Good luck :)